# the self.get_argument doesnt work

Tags: python, tornado

I just started learning Tornado and bumped into the first problem in my hello.py.
I followed the steps and codes given by "Introduction to Tornado". Here is the code.

```
     import tornado.httpserver
     import tornado.ioloop
     import tornado.options
     import tornado.web

     from tornado.options import define, options
     define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

     class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
         def get(self):
            greeting = self.get_argument('greeting','Hello')
            self.write(greeting + ', friendly user!')

     if __name__=="__main__":
        tornado.options.parse_command_line()
        app = tornado.web.Application(handers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)])
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
        http_server.listen(options.port)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

after I run it in other Terminal window by

```
    curl http://localhost:8000/
```

I didn't get the expected answer, which should be

```
    Hello, friendly user!
```

Instead, the respond is something like

```
    [I 121026 18:20:38 web:1359] 301 GET / (127.0.0.1) 1.12ms
```

I am so new to this that I have no idea how to solve it. The problem may sound really stupid buy please do me a favor and help me out! Thanks  lot!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is the primary issue, but you misspelled `handlers` in

```
handers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your domain is not right.I think you can make port=8888,and then in your shell,you can type: 
python hello.py --port=8888    #hello.py is the filename
The url is:localhost:8888